# PHP WP Insert Post

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm struggling a bit to insert a post with the features I require.

```
include ('../wp-load.php');
            $my_post = array(
              'post_title'    => 'title' ,
              'post_content'  => 'some content',
              'post_status'   => 'publish',
              'post_author'   => 1,
              'post_category' => array(34,35),
              'tags_input' => array('tag1,tag2'),
              'the_post_thumbnail' => 526
            );

            // Insert the post into the database
            wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

**Question 1:**

It's all working besides for 'the_post_thumbnail' => 526 - I was hoping that was going to attach the media item id (526) as the featured post image (obviously this isn't working). What is the correct way to do this?

**Question 2:**

Is there a way to get the URL of the post that is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following example that uses the  functions `set_post_thumbnail()` and `get_permalink()`:

```
       $my_post = array(
          'post_title'    => 'title' ,
          'post_content'  => 'some content',
          'post_status'   => 'publish',
          'post_author'   => 1,
          'post_category' => array(34,35),
          'tags_input'    => array('tag1,tag2'),
        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        $pid = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

        if( is_wp_error( $pid ) )
        { 
            // Display error:
            echo $pid->get_error_message();
        }
        else
        {
           // Set featured image to inserted post:
            set_post_thumbnail( $pid, 526 );

           // Get permalink:
            $link = get_permalink( $pid );
        }
```

where we use `is_wp_error()` to make sure the insert was sucessful.

Hope this helps.